# Upload speed for Google Compute instance to Google Drive file transfer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I wanted to know what kind of speeds can be achieved while uploading files from a GC instance to Google Drive using Rest API for large media files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this out before.

For a file of size around 700 Mb, the upload time was around 22 seconds i.e. ~31 Mb/s.